# How do I transfer my StreetPass data from one 3DS system to another?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

I just got a 3DS XL system and I want to move my 3DS profile to the new handheld. Will the System Transfer also transfer my StreetPass progress? I've finished several panels and received several *Find Mii* hats, I would hate to lose this progress just because I got a new system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and did the System Transfer (can be found under Settings -> Other Settings -> System Transfer (3rd page, I believe). My StreetPass data and progress was transferred although data that was stored on SD card (such as some DLC and extra data for some games) was lost.

Comment: If you have to do this again, I highly suggest backing up the SD card data onto your computer or something before you do the transfer, so that you can always put it back on the SD card if it gets lost.

Comment: You can copy-paste the content of an SD-card to another. I had to swap my 2GB SD card with a 32GB one, because my free copy of Monster Hunter didn't fit on it. All DLCs, Virtual Console games and more still worked like a charm after copy-pasting. You will need a PC with an SD card reader for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. Everything from your old 3DS will be moved to your new 3DS. After the transfer is complete, make sure you swap sD cards. (Put your old SD to your new 3DS)